# Django form not updating existing record even when instance is passed

Tags: django, post, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that is used to create and edit a model instance. But when editing the model instance, the form still tries to create a new record and fails because the unique together fields already exist. I am already passing the instance when initializing the form.

views.py

```
def organization_course_detail(request, org_id):
    '''
    Get all courses that are associated with an organization
    '''
    template_name = 'users/organization-course-list.html'
    organization = models.Organization.objects.get(id=org_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print organization.id
        form = forms.CreateOrganizationForm(request.POST, instance=organization)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'form is valid'
            org = form.save(commit=False)
            org.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse('users:org-course-list',
                        kwargs={'org_id': org_id}))
    else:
        form = forms.CreateOrganizationForm(instance=organization)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateOrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    A form used to create a new organization. At the same time,
    we create a new course that is a clone of "Chalk Talk SAT"
    and associate the course with the organization and any student
    that signs up from that organization
    '''

    class Meta:
        model = models.Organization
        fields = ['name', 'country', 'acronym',]
```

models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    '''
    This is a model where we will have every institution
    (test prep centers, governments, schools) that we do workshops
    at or create school accounts for
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank='(Select Country)')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    acronym = models.CharField(max_length=7, help_text="(Up to 7 characters)")
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_org_admins(self):
        return self.admin_for_organizations.all()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('name', 'country')
        )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the entries in your db table? (or can you post them?)

You might try using the django shell and try to execute your code by hand (query the db with an org_id and check the result. Edit a field and save it. Does that work?)

Also I think `blank` can only be True or False here.

`country = CountryField(null=True, blank='(Select Country)')`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank